# Power BI : Add a new value to an existing group

Tags: powerbi

I have a dynamic database (new entries every day), and I grouped values from one column. To group my values, I clicked on the variable I want to group, and picked "New Group".

I grouped my variable such as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otWky.jpg)

1803 will be added soon, and I'd like to add it to group3, but it does not allow me.

Anyone knows how to do that? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I Don't understand totally the logic for choosing 4 digits of column A to grouped them in G1, G2 or G3. 
But, if this depends on the last 2 digits, you can add a calculated column as the following:

```
Grouped_A = IF(SEARCH("01";'Table'[A];1;0 )>0;"G1";IF(SEARCH("02";'Table'[A];1;0 )>0;"G2";"G3"))
```

If is not this logic you want to implement, can you explain us better, please!

Hope can help you.